Action-angle variable construction and the assumption of independent actions
Let $N$ be an $n$-dimensional smooth manifold, $M=T^*N$, and $\omega$ its canonical symplectic structure. Any $H\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ induces a Hamiltonian vector field $X_H$ defined implicitly by $\sigma(Y,X_H)=dH(Y)$ for arbitrary $Y\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(M;TM)$.
Say $f_1,\ldots,f_n\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ are such that $\{f_i,f_j\}=0$ for all $i,j$ and the $df_j$ are linearly independent. This condition (asserted on an open dense set) is the standard definition of a completely integrable system, and the Liouville-Arnold theorem asserts that the compact connected components of joint level sets $f^{-1}(c)$ are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{T}^n$ and so we have that $(f,\theta)\in D\times \mathbb{T}^n$ are (semi-)local coordinates on an open set in $M$, for some $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open.
One can then construct ``action-angle coordinates" locally near an invariant torus, where the action coordinate $I_j$ is obtained by integrating the canonical $1$-form $\xi\cdot dx$ of $M$ over the $n$ generators of the fundamental group of $\mathbb{T}^n$. This is the standard construction in Arnold's book on classical mechanics, Abraham-Marsden and others.
However in this construction, every reference I have seen (e.g. Arnold p283) takes the linear independence of $dI_j$ (so indeed $f\leftrightarrow I$ is a local diffeomorphism) as an $\textit{assumption}$. From this, I imagine that there are examples of integrable systems that satisfy the hypotheses of Liouville-Arnold I gave above but do NOT admit local action angle variable, due to the $f\mapsto I$ map dropping rank.
My questions are:

Is this assumption indeed one that cannot be dropped?
Is there a simple example of such an integrable system?
Is there some sense in which this assumption is a mild one? It appears to be glossed over in statements of theorems about the construction of action-angle variables, only appearing in the proofs.


This assumption 'the $dI_i$s are linearly independent' is superfluous, as it is always satisfied! That is: action-angle coordinates always exist!
Remark. The proof is rather long and convoluted; on a first reading, you might want to restrict to the special case $n=2$, which is already informative.
We start from the existence of the coordinate patch $(f, \theta) \in \mathbb{D}^n \times \mathbb{T}^n$. Let $\omega$ be the restriction of the canonical symplectic form on $M = T^*N$ to this coordinate patch.
Step 1. Our first goal is to understand what is the general appearance of the symplectic form $\omega$ in those coordinates.
We write
$$ \omega = \sum_{i, j = 1}^n c_{ij} d\theta_i \wedge df_j \, + \, \sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} b_{ij} df_i \wedge df_j \, + \,  \sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} a_{ij} d\theta_i \wedge d\theta_j .$$
where the $a_{ij}$s, $b_{ij}$s and $c_{ij}$s are functions of $(f, \theta)$. The 2-form $\omega_0 = \sum_{i, j = 1}^n c_{ij} df_i \wedge d\theta_j$ will play a distinctive role in what follows.
Since every torus $\{ f = \mbox{constant} \}$ is Lagrangian, we have $a_{ij} = 0$ for all $i,j$, i.e.
$$ (\ast) \quad \omega = \sum_{i, j = 1}^n c_{ij} d\theta_i \wedge df_j \, + \, \sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} b_{ij} df_i \wedge df_j .$$
From there, it follows that the non-degeneracy of $\omega$ is equivalent to the non-degeneracy of $\omega_0$. The form $\omega_0$ can be encoded into the square matrix $C := (c_{ij})_{1 \le i, j \le n}$, and the non-degeneracy of $\omega$ amounts to $\mathrm{det} \, C \neq 0$.
In general, $\omega_0$ might not be a closed $2$-form. However, since $d\omega = 0$, we do have the constraints:
$$ (\ast\ast) \quad \mbox{For all $1 \le i,j, k \le n$, } \; \partial_{\theta_i} c_{jk} - \partial_{\theta_j} c_{ik} = 0. $$
Remark. The Poisson commutativity of the $f_j$s adds no further constraint over $(\ast)$. In other words, for any symplectic form satisfying $(\ast)$, the $f_j$s necessarily Poisson commute.
Step 2. We now come to analyse how a linear relation could hold between the $dI_i$s. We know that $\omega = d\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the reading of the canonical 1-form in the coordinate patch.
Let's write $T_v = \{ f = \mbox{constant $n$-vector $v$}\} = \{v\} \times \mathbb{T}^n \subset \mathbb{D}^n \times \mathbb{T}^n$ for $v \in \mathbb{D}^n$. For $1 \le i \le n$, we define the action $I_i : \mathbb{D}^n \times \mathbb{T}^n \overset{\mathrm{proj}}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{D}^n \overset{I_i}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{R}$ as
$$ I_i(v) := \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\theta_i \in \mathbb{T}^1 } \lambda_{(v, \theta)}(\partial_{\theta_i}) d\theta_i \, . $$
(It is understood here that $\theta = (\theta_1, \dots, \theta_n)$ is fixed in the integrand, except for the coordinate $\theta_i$ which varies in $\mathbb{T}^1$. Since $T_v$ is Lagrangian, $I_i(v)$ does not depend on $\theta$. We introduced the normalizing factor $1/2\pi$ for later convenience.)
If $Y = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \partial_{f_k}$, then we obtain (essentially by applying Stokes' theorem to a cylinder 'spanned' by $\partial_{\theta_i}$ and $Y$)
$$(dI_i)_v(Y) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\theta_i \in \mathbb{T}^1 } \omega(\partial_{\theta_i}, Y) d\theta_i = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\theta_i \in \mathbb{T}^1 } (\omega_0)(\partial_{\theta_i}, Y) d\theta_i .$$
In fact, since $I_i$ does not depend on the choice of the $\theta$, we can average over $(\theta_1, \dots, \hat{\theta_i}, \dots, \theta_n) \in \mathbb{T}^{n-1}$ to get
$$(dI_i)_v(Y) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \int_{\theta \in \mathbb{T}^n } \omega(\partial_{\theta_i}, Y) d\theta = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \int_{\theta \in \mathbb{T}^n } (\omega_0)(\partial_{\theta_i}, Y) d\theta .$$
Hence, having a linear relation $0 = \sum_{i=1}^n r_i (dI_i)_v$ at some point $v \in \mathbb{D}^n$ amounts to having $0 = \sum_{i=1}^n r_i (dI_i)_v(Y)$ for every $Y$ of the form $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \partial_{f_k}$, which in turn amounts to having for every $1 \le j \le n$ (by taking $Y = \partial_{f_j}$)
$$ 0 = \sum_{i=1}^n r_i \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \int_{\theta \in \mathbb{T}^n } c_{ij}(v, \theta) d\theta .$$
In other words, a linear relation $0 = \sum_{i=1}^n r_i (dI_i)_v$ exists if and only if $r = (r_1, \dots, r_n)$ lies in the kernel of the matrix
$$\bar{C}(v) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\int_{\theta \in \mathbb{T}^n } C(v, \theta) d\theta = \left( \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \int_{\theta \in \mathbb{T}^n } c_{ij}(v, \theta) d\theta \right)_{ij}.$$
(More generally, the number of such relations equals the dimension of $\mathrm{Ker} \, \bar{C}(v)$.)
In conclusion of Step 2, the existence of a nontrivial linear relation $0 = \sum_{i=1}^n r_i (dI_i)_v$ amounts to having
$$ (\spadesuit) \quad  \mathrm{det} \, \bar{C}(v) = 0$$
(although $\mathrm{det} \, {C}(v, \theta)$ never vanishes).
Step 3.  It is easy to find an invertible matrix-valued function $C(v, \theta)$ satisfying $(\spadesuit)$, e.g. for $n=2$,
$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} \mathrm{cos}(\theta_1) & \mathrm{sin}(\theta_1) \\ - \mathrm{sin}(\theta_1) & \mathrm{cos}(\theta_1) \end{array}  \right). $$
However, an appropriate example would satisfy $(\ast \ast)$ too, since we want $C$ to correspond to the $\omega_0$ of the symplectic form $\omega$, as considered above. Our last goal is to prove that this is impossible:
Lemma. For a symplectic form $\omega$ of the type $(\ast)$, the corresponding matrix-valued function $C(v, \theta)$ (which satisfies $(\ast \ast)$) cannot satisfy $(\spadesuit)$ for any $v \in \mathbb{D}^n$.
Proof. We shall prove the following: if, for some arbitrary fixed $v \in \mathbb{D}^n$, a smooth matrix-valued function $C(v, \theta)$ satisfies $(\ast \ast)$, then
$$ (\clubsuit) \quad \mathrm{det} \, \bar{C}(v) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \int_{\theta \in \mathbb{T}^n} \mathrm{det} \, C(v, \theta) \, d\theta \, .$$
(This identity is clear for $n=1$, but it is nontrivial for $n \ge 2$ due to the nonlinearity of the determinant function.) Hence if $C$ satisfies $(\spadesuit)$, it follows that the (continuous) function $\mathrm{det} \, C$ vanishes somewhere over $\mathbb{T}_v$, so that $C$ does not correspond to a nondegenerate 2-form $\omega_0$.
For simplicity, we drop $v$ from the notations below.
(i) We can write the smooth function $C(\theta)$ as a Fourier series:
$$ C(\theta) = \sum_{\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}^n} C^{\alpha} e^{\sqrt{-1} \alpha \cdot \theta} \, .$$
Here, $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n)$ is a multi-index, $\alpha \cdot \theta = \alpha_1 \theta_1 + \dots + \alpha_n \theta_n$, and we introduced the coefficient matrices $C^{\alpha}$ (where $\alpha$ is an index, not an exponent). (Since $C$ is real matrix-valued in our applications, we have $C^{-\alpha} = (C^{\alpha})^*$ for all $\alpha$, but this identity won't play a role.)
(ii) The constraints $(\ast \ast)$ become:
$$ \mbox{For all $\alpha$ and all $i,j,k$, } \; \alpha_i C^{\alpha}_{jk} - \alpha_j C^{\alpha}_{ik} = 0.  $$
For $\alpha = 0$, this constraint is void: the matrix $C^{0}$ can be arbitrary. For $\alpha \neq 0$, there is some nonzero 'reference component' $\alpha_* := \alpha_{i_*}$ (which, if there are many nonzero components $\alpha_j$, we shall take to be the component of minimal absolute value, and positive if possible), and so we obtain $C^{\alpha}_{ij} = (\alpha_i/\alpha_*)C_{i_* j}$, i.e., all rows of $C^{\alpha}$ are multiples of the 'reference row' $C^{\alpha}_* = (C^{\alpha}_{i_* 1}, \dots, C^{\alpha}_{i_* n})$.
(iii) We compute $\bar{C} = C^0 $, hence $\mathrm{det} \, \bar{C} = \mathrm{det} \, C^0$.
(iv) Denoting by $S_n$ the group of permutations on $n$ elements and by $s_{\sigma}$ the sign of a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$, we have
\begin{align}
\mathrm{det} \, C(\theta) &= \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} s_{\sigma} \, C^{(1)}_{1 \sigma(1)} \cdot \dots \cdot C^{(n)}_{n \sigma(n)} \\
 &= \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \sum_{\alpha_{(1)}, \dots, \alpha_{(n)} \in \mathbb{Z}^n }s_{\sigma} \, C^{\alpha_{(1)}}_{1 \sigma(1)} \cdot \dots \cdot C^{\alpha_{(n)}}_{n \sigma(n)} \, e^{\sqrt{-1} \, (\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{(j)}) \cdot \theta} \, , 
\end{align}
where the symbols $(j)$ in $C^{(j)}$ and $\alpha_{(j)}$ are bookkeeping devices. Averaging over $\theta \in \mathbb{T}^n$, we get
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{(2 \pi)^n} \, \int_{\theta \in \mathbb{T}^n} \mathrm{det} \, C(\theta) \, d\theta &= 
  \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \sum_{\alpha_{(1)}, \dots, \alpha_{(n)} \in \mathbb{Z}^n 
 \\ \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{(j)} = 0 }s_{\sigma} \, C^{\alpha_{(1)}}_{1 \sigma(1)} \cdot \dots \cdot C^{\alpha_{(n)}}_{n \sigma(n)} \\
&= \sum_{(\alpha_{(1)}, \dots, \alpha_{(n)}) \in (\mathbb{Z}^n)^n 
 \\ \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{(j)} = 0 } \mathrm{det} \, C^{(\alpha_{(1)}, \dots,\alpha_{(n)} )} \, , 
\end{align}
where we defined $C^{(\alpha_{(1)}, \dots,\alpha_{(n)} )}$ as the matrix whose $i$th row is given by the $i$th row of the matrix $C^{\alpha_{(i)}}$, i.e., $C^{(\alpha_{(1)}, \dots,\alpha_{(n)} )}_{ij} = C^{\alpha_{(i)}}_{ij}$.
Next we define an equivalence relation on $n$-tuples of $n$-indices $\alpha_{(1)}, \dots, \alpha_{(n)} \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ (satisfying $\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{(j)} = 0$) as follows. Given an ordered $n$-tuple $A = (\alpha_{(1)}, \dots, \alpha_{(n)}) \in (\mathbb{Z}^n)^n$ (satisfying $\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{(j)} = 0$), the equivalence class $G_A = [A]$ consists of those $n$-tuples $A' = (\alpha'_{(1)}, \dots, \alpha'_{(n)}) \in (\mathbb{Z}^n)^n$ (and satisfying $\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha'_{(j)} = 0$) that are obtained from $A$ by permuting the positions of the nonzero $\alpha_{(j)}$s, i.e.

$\alpha'_{(j)} = 0$ iff $\alpha_{(j)} = 0$, and
if $J_A := \{ j \in \{1, \dots, n\} \, : \, \alpha_{(j)} \neq 0\}$ then there exists $\pi \in \mathrm{perm}(J_A)$ such that $\alpha'_{(j)} = \alpha'_{(\pi(j))}$ for all $j \in J_A$.

Let $\mathcal{G}$ denote the collection of such equivalence classes. Then
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{(2 \pi)^n} \, \int_{\theta \in \mathbb{T}^n} \mathrm{det} \, C(\theta) \, d\theta &= 
 \sum_{G_A \in \mathcal{G}} \sum_{A' \in G_A } \mathrm{det} \, C^{A'} \, . 
\end{align}
(v) Consider a $n$-tuple $A = (\alpha_{(1)}, \dots, \alpha_{(n)})$ having at least one nonzero $\alpha_{(j)}$ (i.e. such that $J_A \neq \varnothing$). It is convenient to introduce the subgroup $S_A \subset S_n$ of those permutations supported in $J_A \subset \{1, \dots, n\}$; any $A' \in G_A$ can thus be thought of as obtained as $A' = \pi \cdot A = (\alpha_{(\pi(1))}, \dots, \alpha_{(\pi(n))})$. Then we compute
\begin{align}
\sum_{A' \in G_A } \mathrm{det} \, C^{A'} = \sum_{\pi \in S_A} \mathrm{det} \, C^{\pi \cdot A} \, .
\end{align}
Now for each $j \in J_A$, the $n$-index $\alpha_{(j)}$ is nonzero, and thus from (ii) above, the $i$th row of $C^{\alpha_{(j)}}$ is $(\alpha_{(j)i}/\alpha_{(j)*}) C^{\alpha_{(j)}}_{i_* }$. Also, for $A' \in G_A$, let's introduce the matrix $M^{A'}$ obtained from $C^{A'}$ by, if $j \in J_A$, replacing the $j$th row of $C^{A'}$ (which is the $j$th row of $C^{\alpha'_{(j)}}$) by the reference row of $C^{A'}$. We note that if $A' = \pi \cdot A$, then $M^{A'} = \pi \cdot M^A$, where the latter action is by permutations of rows. Combining all this, we get
\begin{align}
\sum_{\pi \in S_A} \mathrm{det} \, C^{\pi \cdot A} &= \sum_{\pi \in S_A} (\prod_{j \in J_A} \dfrac{\alpha_{(\pi(j)) j}}{\alpha_{(\pi(j))*}}) \, \mathrm{det} \, M^{(\pi \cdot A)} \\
&= \sum_{\pi \in S_A} \dfrac{\prod_{j \in J_A} \alpha_{(\pi(j)) j}}{\prod_{j \in J_A} \alpha_{(j)*}} \, \mathrm{det} \, (\pi \cdot M^{ A}) \\
&= \left( \sum_{\pi \in S_A} s_{\pi} \, \prod_{j \in J_A} \alpha_{(\pi(j)) j} \right) \, \dfrac{\mathrm{det} \, (M^{ A})}{\prod_{j \in J_A} \alpha_{(j)*}} \, .
\end{align}
Going back to thinking of $\pi \in S_A$ as an element $\pi \in \mathrm{perm}(J_A)$, we get
\begin{align}
\sum_{\pi \in S_A} s_{\pi} \, \prod_{j \in J_A} \alpha_{(\pi(j)) j} &= \sum_{\pi \in \mathrm{perm}(J_A)} s_{\pi} \, \prod_{j \in J_A} \alpha_{(\pi(j)) j} \\
&= \sum_{\pi \in \mathrm{perm}(J_A)} s_{\pi} \, \prod_{j \in J_A} \alpha_{(j) \pi(j)} \\
&= \mathrm{det} \, \tilde{A} \, ,
\end{align}
where $\tilde{A}$ is the $(J_A \times J_A)$-matrix whose $j$th row is the $J_A$-index $\alpha_{(j)}|_{J_A}$ (the tuple of indices $(\alpha_{(j)k})_{k \in J_A}$). At last, we use the fact that $A = (\alpha_{(1)}, \dots, \alpha_{(n)})$ satisfies $0 = \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{(j)} = \sum_{j \in J_A} \alpha_{(j)}$; this implies $0 = \sum_{j \in J_A} \alpha_{(j)|_{J_A}}$, which implies that the rows of $\tilde{A}$ are linearly dependent, hence $\mathrm{det} \, \tilde{A} = 0$. Retracing our steps in (v), we conclude that if $A$ has at least one nonzero $\alpha_{(j)}$, then
\begin{align}
\sum_{A' \in G_A } \mathrm{det} \, C^{A'} = 0 \, .
\end{align}
(vi) From (iv) and (v) it follows that
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{(2 \pi)^n} \, \int_{\theta \in \mathbb{T}^n} \mathrm{det} \, C(\theta) \, d\theta &= 
 \sum_{A' \in G_0 } \mathrm{det} \, C^{A'} = \mathrm{det} \, C^0 \, . 
\end{align}
Combining this and (iii), we proved $(\clubsuit)$ and the lemma... and answered OP's question. QED
